# mouse/tap events in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, mouseevent

I am using C#, Silverlight, WP7.

What is the difference between a Tap event and the sequence of MouseLeftButtonDown and MouseLeftButtonUp events? Also why doesn't a Tap event always trigger MouseLeftButtonDown/MouseLeftButtonUp in sequence? Are these events any different in simulation on the computer and deployed on a phone?

I can't find this in the documentation and my own tests seem to imply that a really quick click on the screen won't always generate a MouseLeftButtonDown/MouseLeftButtonUp sequence. Are these mutually exclusive events? If not, what is the order of events?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the mouse events are available on WP7, they are not necessarily reliable.

> User input in Windows Phone includes manipulation events, mouse
> events, and touch events.
>
> Manipulation events are the recommended way to handle user input. Unless you have a  specific need, you should avoid using mouse events
> in your Silverlight applications for Windows Phone for performance and
> hardware compatibility reasons. Instead, you should use manipulation
> events. You can also use Tap, DoubleTap, and Hold events on any
> elements that derive from UIElement such as the base controls.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff967560%28v=VS.92%29.aspx